# Using OpenLayers Selectfeature get mouse position?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, features

How do I get mouse coordinates after a SelectFeature, which returns the feature by itself?

Answer (score 3):

When you init the map add this control:

```
mapMousePosition = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection(displayProjection)
});
```

In your handler get lonLat like this:

```
 var lonLat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(
      new OpenLayers.Pixel(
         mapMousePosition.lastXy.x,
         mapMousePosition.lastXy.y
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with these ways:

```
feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat()
```

or

```
map.events.register("click", map, function(e) { 
    var latlon = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy) ;
    alert(lonlat)
});
```

or

```
new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer,{
    hover:true,
    eventListeners:{
      onSelect:function(e){
        alert(e.feature.geometry)
    }
});
```

or

```
layer.events.on({
            "featureselected": function(e) {       
            alert(e)
            }
});
```

Comment: Aragon, I think he is asking for `mouse coordinates` (mostly to display Popup) and not `map coordinates`. What your answer telling is to get map coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

my strategy (very resource intensive) is to listen to  `mousemove` and constantly saving x and y values in global variables.

```
var mouseLat, mouseLon;
function init(){
  ...
  map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {
    var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
    var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position);
    var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
    mouseLat = lonlatTransf.lat;
    mouseLon = lonlatTransf.lon;
    OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = "Lat: "+ mouseLat+" | Lon: "+mouseLon;
  });
  ...
}
```

when the feature is selected, i access these values from inside `onFeatureSelect(event)`

Comment: To decrease resource consumption, use debounce/throttle techniques http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Try this for version 4 or higher:

```
var mouse_position = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
});
map.addControl(mouse_position);
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the [answer of @LaurentiuTurcu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155524/115) I set up a jsfiddle which demonstrates how to show the popup at the last mousePosition when you select a feature:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/2asrpnm8/