# GeoExt Toolbar Mouse Position

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js, mouse-position

I am new to GeoExt and OpenLayers world. I am currently using OpenLayers 2 and GeoExt 2. I want to add a mouse position on the toolbar. Currently my mouse position is on the lower right corner of the mappanel and where my map description is suppose to be, I have tried [this](http://trac.geoext.org/ticket/195) and it is not working, complaining that GeoExt.ux is not defined.
I have also tried [Get mouse position in OpenGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82874/get-mouse-position-in-opengeo/159720#159720) then items: [pos] on the toolbar but still this is not working only creating a small button.

Comment: check this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22240/openlayers-selectfeature-get-mouse-position

Answer (score 1):

Create an [Ext.toolbar.TextItem](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.TextItem) and create your OpenLayers [MousePosition-Control](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/MousePosition-js.html) in the render-Event of the TextItem, so you can pass the TextItems's Div to the Control.

Like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.TextItem', {
    listeners: {
        render: function(textitem) {
            var ctrl = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition();
            ctrl.div = textitem.getEl().dom;
            // map is the ref to your OL map instance
            map.addControl(ctrl); 
        } 
    }
});
```